# Error Loading Operating System - SATA External Hard Drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I bought a SATA to USB adapter to attempt to use my labtop's hard drive as an external one for my desktop. If I plug the adapter into my desktop after already booting the current OS, I can see my files just fine. However, whenever I restart the computer, and change the boot order to put the USB device first I receive an Error Loading Operating System message. The old hard drive has XP on it.

What might the issue be?

Thanks much!

Comment: The version of Windows on your external USB laptop drive does not know about the desktop hardware and is loading the wrong device drivers.

Comment: I think that your system detect the external HDD as SATA drive no an USB drive.However, You should install the OS on external hard drive when the external HDD connect to this PC and you should choose this external HDD for destination path in installation wizard. after that you can boot from the external HDD.

Comment: @DavidPostill , Sorry for the stupid question, but is there a way to make it load the correct drivers?